# Argument of type 'BehaviorSubject<MediaSuffix>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Observable<MediaSuffix>'

Tags: angular, jasmine, observable, karma-jasmine, behaviorsubject

There is an error in one my spec files:

`const a = jasmine.createSpyObj<AppService>('as', ['getAppsForUserByRoleObservable']); const msMock = jasmine.createSpyObj<MediaService>('ms', ['getMediaSuffix']); const observable = new BehaviorSubject(MediaSuffix.Lg); msMock.getMediaSuffix.and.returnValue(observable);`

It showing an error for "observable" on the last line. Putting my cursor over gives this error: "Argument of type 'BehaviorSubject' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Observable'.
Type 'BehaviorSubject' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable': _isScalar, _trySubscribe, _subscribe"

[the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yef0r.png)

[the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtrJk.png)

How do I fix this?

I have tried adding an "of" from rxjs, but it did not work.

Comment: To fix this, you can convert the `BehaviorSubject` to an Observable using `asObservable()`

Comment: @tdimoff can you explain how to do that?

Comment: Like this: `const observable = new BehaviorSubject(MediaSuffix.Lg).asObservable();`.